# Django Querysets - Filter objects by Boolean values in a related object

Tags: django, django-queryset

I would like to create a model manager for my Purchase model:

```
class Purchase(models.Model)
    number = models.IntegerField

class InventoryLog(models.Model)
    purchase = models.ForeignKey(Purchase)
    sold_out = models.BooleanField(default=false)
```

I would like my model manager to return any `Purchase` objects that are not related to an `InventoryLog` object with a `sold_out` value of `True`

Is there a way to handle this with a queryset, Q object or F object, or will I need to resort to a for loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe `Purchase.objects().exclude(inventorylog__sold_out=True)` will do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use manage for your model, how about this:

```
#models.py
class PurhchaseNotSoldOut(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(PurchaseNotSoldOut, self).get_queryset()\
                          .exclude(purhcase_logs__sold_out=True)

class Purchase(models.Model)
    number = models.IntegerField

    notSoldOut = PurchaseNotSoldOut()

class InventoryLog(models.Model)
    purchase = models.ForeignKey(Purchase, related_name='purchase_logs')
    sold_out = models.BooleanField(default=false)
```

Code example **UPDATED** thanks to Peter DeGlopper comment.

Comment: 1) incorrect syntax in your `filter` clause, use `__` to follow fk relations in filters. 2) those two queries are not equivalent, because a `Purchase` can have many `InventoryLog`s. `filter(purchase_log__sold_out=False)` finds those with at least one not sold out, `exclude()` excludes those with any sold out (so it returns only those without any sold out).

Comment: Is there any advantage to overwriting `get_queryset` as opposed to just returning a new one?

Comment: Overwriting `get_queryset` is how you typically make a custom manager: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/managers/#modifying-a-manager-s-initial-queryset

Comment: Ah, I've been writing new functions as it looks cleaner and I can get more verbose. ie: `Purchase.inventory.in_stock()`